# Scientific Notation

Tags: jquery, coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I need to store and display a number with no limits on leading zero's to the right of the decimal point and no trailing zeros, for example: .000000001 as soon as I enter a number with more than 7 zeros it gets converted to scientific notation.  I also don't want trailing zero's for example: .00000000100000.

I'm using coldfusion and jquery.

What's the best datatype to use in the SQL table? How do I display on the web page the original number that was used?

Comment: I suspect you'll need to store it as a string rather than a numeric, as all numerics have precision limitations. Given you're asking a DB question, tagging your question with the DB platform concerned might be a good move. Neither JQuery nor ColdFusion are really relevant to the answer to your question, I think.

Comment: One way to manage this would be to use numberFormat() in ColdFusion.

Answer (score 1):

There are two options... 
1. Format the number, convert it to a string, then store the string.
2. Store the number as it was generated and format the value when it is displayed.

I suggest trying to make the second option work for you because 1) It's a best practice to store numbers as numbers, and 2) you may need to manipulate the value or use the value in a calculation. If it is stored as a string, you need to convert it back to a number *of the right type* before using it.

One thing to consider is that ColdFusion has its own odbc abstraction that may do some numeric conversion when numbers are stored in the database. This may affect how the numbers are inserted and retrieved from the database so you might have to do some formatting before using or displaying the data anyway. Each time you convert a number between data types, or between different systems that define precision differently (i.e. JavaScript, ColdFusion, MSSQL), some rounding might introduce errors so validate whatever option you choose with known data.